# Trouble displaying contours in R and ggplot with basic dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot some NMDS co-ordinates as x and y, and use a diversity measure (shannon)to plot as a contour but I keep getting the following error and I can't see why...

```
Error in if (empty(new)) return(data.frame()) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

My code is:

```
all_merge <-read.table("test.txt", header=TRUE)

 p <- ggplot(all_merge, aes(NMDS1, NMDS2, z = shannon))
 p + geom_contour()
```

and my dataset is:

```
NMDS1   NMDS2   shannon
-0.287555952    -0.129887595    9.516558582
-0.314104852    -0.048655648    8.985087924
-0.214910534    -0.127167065    8.928241917
-0.341295065    -0.296282805    8.315476782
-0.470025718    0.083835083 8.494348157
-0.429386114    0.044064347 8.669813919
-0.427608469    0.124631936 8.15886319
-0.584412991    0.257278736 8.469688185
-0.436526047    -0.070633108    8.496878956
-0.584707076    0.120411579 8.319057817
0.183493022 0.445239412 5.611249955
0.172968855 0.583787121 5.728358304
-0.404838098    -0.0271276  8.679667562
-0.458718755    -0.05638174 8.714026645
0.458621093 -0.186746574    8.094002558
1.148457698 0.044192391 6.058046032
0.346825668 0.258443444 6.682765975
0.753149083 -0.393018506    7.622032803
1.331546069 -0.515095457    5.784195943
0.236285309 0.2553056   7.210095451
0.346995457 -0.816928807    7.198583726
0.137626646 0.129803823 7.663931393
0.340733689 -0.461201268    5.845269914
-0.675116235    -0.037255181    8.371975231
-0.656523041    -0.025798291    8.438133054
-0.578757804    -0.073169316    8.411583639
-0.602672875    0.015207904 8.137468395
0.413598703 0.320133927 5.91489704
0.891714173 1.032329752 3.612230592
0.378252162 0.054121091 7.903450498
0.401158365 0.009307957 8.164654685
-0.074266368    -0.512745143    8.956733268
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`geom_contour` (`stat_contour`) does not work on irregular grids (see [**here**](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/316)). One way to create a regular grid is to use the interpolation function `interp` in package `akima`.

```
library(akima)
library(reshape2)

# interpolate data to regular grid
d1 <- with(all_merge, interp(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, z = shannon))

# melt the z matrix in d1 to long format for ggplot
d2 <- melt(d1$z, na.rm = TRUE)
names(d2) <- c("x", "y", "shannon")

# add NMDS1 and NMDS2 from d1 using the corresponding index in d2
d2$NMDS1 <- d1$x[d2$x]
d2$NMDS2 <- d1$y[d2$y]

# plot
ggplot(data = d2, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, fill = shannon, z = shannon)) +
  geom_tile() +
  stat_contour()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. I have been able to reproduce your figure and I've added on some additional metadata from an envfit.
Purely for aesthetics, is it possible to increase the resolution by reducing the square size? Or is that limited by my data?

Comment: Good to hear that you found my answer useful! Regarding resolution, you may have a look at the arguments `x0` (and `y0`) in `?interp`. "vector of x-coordinates of output grid. The default is 40 points evenly spaced over the range of x". You may try to increase `x0` in your `interp` call like e.g. this: `xo = seq(min(NMDS1), max(NMDS1), length = 60)`