# Creating GW contours using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a novice at R coding and am trying to plot GW contours using X (Easting) and Y (Northing) cords and GW level (rswl) data in ggplot. An example of the data that I am trying to plot is:

```
    X Obs_No      Season  Easting Northing  rswl
1  56 ADE146 Winter 2017 275638.7  6131431  5.72
2 113 YAT099 Winter 2017 271723.0  6133405  3.16
4 227 YAT066 Winter 2017 276503.0  6135636  2.31
5 292 YAT053 Winter 2017 277780.8  6139285 -2.30
6 400 YAT129 Winter 2017 282065.1  6146759  5.60
7 509 PTA040 Winter 2017 270868.0  6150199  1.68
```

An example of the code I have tried is:

```
ggplot(data)+
  aes(x = Easting, y = Northing, z = rswl, fill = rswl)+
  geom_tile()+
  geom_contour(colour = "white", alpha = 0.5)+
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", na.value = "white") +
  theme_bw()
```

but it comes up with "Not possible to generate contour data"

Something else I tried with 1 of my datasets is:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Easting, y = Northing, z = rswl)) + 
  geom_density_2d(colour = "black")+
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(Obs_No)))+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
  ggtitle("Tomw.T2 Winter 2017.csv")
```

This seems to be contours based on the distribution of points and has nothing to do with the GW level.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you run `dput(data)` and post the output as sample data?

Comment: Sounds like your rswl values may not be evenly spaced, which causes problems for contour generation. From `?geom_contour`: "Contouring tends to work best when x and y form a (roughly) evenly spaced grid. If you data is not evenly spaced, you may want to interpolate to a grid before visualising." See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894609/trouble-displaying-contours-in-r-and-ggplot-with-basic-dataset) for possible workaround using `interp` from the `akima` package.

Comment: thank you so much - it worked. I knew that there was something wrong with the coordinates/grid!